# how to captor a hashmap inside a nested method in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, hashmap, mockito

The class and its methods as follows.

```
Class MyClass{
   method1(){
      method2(para1)
   }

   method2(para1){
      HashMap<String,String> users=new HashMap<>();
      ...
      para1.setUsers(users)
   }
}
```

I want to captor the **users** hashmap for unit testings by mocking the MyClass. How I can complete this with mockito?

Comment: what are you doing with `HashMap users` inside the `method2()`? You can only capture side-effects, so if that `users` doesn't "leave" the `method2()` then there is **no way** to capture said map

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `para1` is either a `@Mock` or a `@Spy` along the lines of:

```java
@Mock
private Para1Type para1;
// or
@Spy
private Para1Type para1 = new Para1Type();
```

then you can use a simple `ArgumentCaptor`

```java
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, String>> usersCaptor;
```

And then use `verify()` inside your test:

```java
// call the method under test
myClass.method2(para1);

// verify the call took place
verify(para1).setUsers(usersCaptor.capture());

// extract the users
Map<String, String> users = usersCaptor.getValue();

// do something with users
```